# Installing Android Studio on Mac - offline

Tags: android, macos, gradle

I try to install Android Studio on a Mac as offline version.
Therefore I installed Android Studio then added ADK folder and have problems to get the gradle running.

Obviously it has no connection to google but I did go to settings -> deploy... -> gradle and changed to local gradle 6.5

Before local Gradle
[image]

After local Gradle
[image]

Click on enable offline mode
[image]

I am really confused how to install Android Studio on a Mac if it is an offline laptop.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You should connect it to the internet at least one time to download the latest gradle.